# how I can populate array of contents in html5 table using javascript?

Tags: html

I have an html table and I need to populate the contents of an array into the table dynamically and also,If the content exceeds more than ten row need to create pagination

Comment: We really need more detail, like how the table is in term of row/column, what exactly is inside the array and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest jQuery DataTables to provide pagination, sorting and filtering very easily.  All you need to do is emit standard  markup, and then initialise the DataTables plugin.

You can populate the  from numerous data sources, for example via AJAX or just load it into the page.

See http://www.datatables.net/

Please clarify what you mean by "populate the contents of an array into the table".